# if(condition) is not working within asynctask

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

I have this code with asynctask and json:

```
class loginn extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
     String u;
     String usuario = user.getText().toString();
     String contraseña = pass.getText().toString();
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {


                HttpClient httpclient2 = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost2 = new HttpPost("****");

                     try
                     {
                     nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                     nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user", usuario));
                     nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", contraseña));                     
                     httppost2.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                     HttpResponse response2 = httpclient2.execute(httppost2);
                     HttpEntity entity = response2.getEntity();
                     u = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                     if(u.equals("1")){

                     runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(login.this, "yes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                             toast.show();
                        }
                        });
                             }else
                             {
                                 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                    public void run() {
                                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(login.this, "no", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                         toast.show();
                                    }
                                    });
                             }
                 }
                 catch(Exception e)
                 {

                 }
                    return null;


        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            }
```

the query of php is good, but the "if" always returns "no", but if I put the variable "u" on a toast, it returns "1" when exists the user and pass, and "0" when not exists.

the php is:

```
<?php  

$con = mysql_connect('***', '****', '*****');  
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");  
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");  
$user = $_POST['user'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
if( $con )  
{  
mysql_select_db('*****');  
$query = "select * from usuarios where username='$user' and passw='$pass'";    
$res = mysql_query($query);
$count = 0;

    while($row = mysql_fetch_object($res))
      {
         $count++;
      }
if($count==1)
{
   echo json_encode(1);
}else
  {
    echo json_encode(0);
  }
}
php?>
```

Comment: Try equalsIgnoreCase() and check whether its working or not.

Comment: try Integer.parseInt(u)==1 OR EQUALIGNORECASE

Comment: What happens when you log the response :|

Comment: Of topic but, don't start a new Runnable inside an AsyncTask. Make UI changes in "onPostExecute".

Comment: it  still returns "No", I call the asyncktask in a "onclick" method with new loginn().execute();

Comment: @kgandroid I try with Integer.parseInt(u)==1 and the toast doesn't show and with equalignorecase it always returns "no"

Comment: @stealthjong the log say "1" when I insert a valid user and passwd, and "0" if not.

Comment: I have just tried with if(!u.equals("1")) and always shows "yes" :/

Comment: So apparently, u is NOT "1", but it might have spaces or something somewhere. Check with the following: `u.length()` (should be 1), `System.out.println("'" + u + "'")`, `foreach (char c : u.toCharArray()) { System.out.println("" + ((int)c))}`

Comment: @stealthjong System.out.println(u.length()); returns 5!!

Comment: The simple explanation should be the good one : the response contains something more that "1". Try `if(Pattern.compile("1").matcher(u).find())`

Comment: @ToYonos clap, clap, clap. it works! thank you!

Comment: I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A space or or some invisible character must be also present in the response.

Try this :

```
if(Pattern.compile("1").matcher(u).find())
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
if(Integer.valueOf(u) == 1)
```

hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
class loginn extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>{
  String usuario = user.getText().toString();
  String contraseña = pass.getText().toString();

  @Override
  protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
    HttpClient httpclient2 = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost2 = new HttpPost("****");
    try {
      nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
      nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user", usuario));
      nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", contraseña));                     
      httppost2.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
      HttpResponse response2 = httpclient2.execute(httppost2);
      HttpEntity entity = response2.getEntity();
      String u = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
      System.out.println("length " + u.length()); //should be 1
      System.out.println("'" + u + "'"); //should be '1'
      for (char c : u.toCharArray())
        System.out.println("current = " + ((int)c)); //should be 49, if more than one => look up in ASCII table
      return u.equals("1");
    }
    catch(Exception e) { 
      return false;
    }
  }

  protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    Toast.makeText(login.this, result ? "yes" : "no", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
}
```

Above code is your code, but optimized a little, and made better readable.

Apparently, `u` is **NOT** equal to `"1"`. This might be, because of characters in `u` which you don't see, for example spaces.
Which means your if-condition works flawlessly. You should focus on what `u` is. You can do that by debugging with the statements I put into your code.

UPDATE

```
12-12 11:38:52.858: I/System.out(4445): length 5 
12-12 11:38:52.858: I/System.out(4445): '1 ' 
12-12 11:38:52.862: I/System.out(4445): current = 49 
12-12 11:38:52.862: I/System.out(4445): current = 9 
12-12 11:38:52.862: I/System.out(4445): current = 9 
12-12 11:38:52.862: I/System.out(4445): current = 9 
12-12 11:38:52.862: I/System.out(4445): current = 9 
and the toast shows "no" –
```

Seeing your log statement, some horizontal tabs get added to the response.

Since the first entry is `49`, you can use

```
return u.length() > 0 && u.charAt(0) == '1';
```

That should fix your problem, but you'd still have to find out why this happens

EDIT

You may try to use `EntityUtils.toString` with a charset: `EntityUtils.toString(entity, "UTF-8)"`

Comment: 12-12 11:38:52.858: I/System.out(4445): length 5
12-12 11:38:52.858: I/System.out(4445): '1    '
12-12 11:38:52.862: I/System.out(4445): current = 49
12-12 11:38:52.862: I/System.out(4445): current = 9
12-12 11:38:52.862: I/System.out(4445): current = 9
12-12 11:38:52.862: I/System.out(4445): current = 9
12-12 11:38:52.862: I/System.out(4445): current = 9

and the toast shows "no"